# How to get the file path in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, google-cloud-storage

I would like to send a file to Google Cloud Platform using their client library such on this this example (Node.js code sample): https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects

[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
const s3Bucket = 'bucket_name';
const s3Key = 'folder/filename.extension';
const filePath = s3Bucket + "/" + s3Key;

await storage.bucket(s3Bucket).upload(filePath, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
});
```

But when I do this there is an error:

> "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'ch.ebu.mcma.google.eu-west-1.ibc.websiteExtract/AudioJobResults/audioGoogle.flac'"

I also tried to send the path I got in AWS Console (Copy path button) "s3://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ch.ebu.mcma.google.eu-west-1.ibc.website/ExtractAudioJobResults/audioGoogle.flac", but did not work.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to copy and S3-Object to Google Cloud Storage directly? I doubt that's possible without downloading it first and that's not what the first example shows. In fact the comment explicitly says `Local file to upload` the emphasis here is local. S3 is not local storage ;-)

Comment: Yes I would like to send a file that is stored in AWS S3 Bucket to Google Cloud Storage. I do not know it it is "directly" or not. Thank for your message, I think I understood how to handle this now. Actually I thought S3 was a sort of local storage :-)

Comment: Glad we cleared up the misunderstanding, I suggest you download the file from S3 to local storage in Lambda (`/tmp`) and upload it from there to Google Cloud Storage. Note that there is a limit of 500MB for /tmp.

Comment: Thanky you @Maurice, this is what I have done and it worked as expected. Please add your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to copy data from S3 to Google Cloud Storage directly. This is not what your example/tutorial shows. The sample code assumes that you upload a local copy of the data to Google Cloud Storage. S3 is **not** local storage.

**How you could do it:**

1. Download the data to `/tmp` in your Lambda function
2. Use the sample code above to upload the data from `/tmp`
3. (Optionally) Remove the uploaded data from `/tmp`

**A word of caution:** The available storage under `/tmp` is currently limited to 500MB. If you want to upload/copy files larger than that this won't work. Also beware that the lambda execution environment might be re-used so cleaning up after yourself (i.e. step 3) is probably a good idea if you plan to copy lots of files.